# Ng-repeat com valor pré-selecionado

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou construindo um `CRUD` completo, e na hora de fazer o editar, estou com um problema no `ng-repeat`. Para salvar, tenho um formulário com um `select` e `ng-repeat` que contém as funções que um colaborador pode ter (Coordenador, supervisor, professor, etc). Até ai tudo bem, ele salva no banco tudo certinho, com o id da função. Porém na hora de editar, ele preenche esse formulário com todas as informações, menos o `select` com o `ng-repeat`, que fica "vazio". Preciso deixar `select` com o valor pré-selecionado com o valor do id que vier do banco, porém não estou conseguindo.

Esse é meu `select` com `ng-repeat`

```html
 <div  ng-controller="funcoesController">
        <div class="form-group error">
            <label for="inputFuncao" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Função </label>
                
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select name="funcao" ng-model="colaborador.funcao_id" ng-required="true">
                    <option ng-repeat="f in tbfuncao" value="{{f.id}}">
                      {{f.descricao}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <span class="help-inline" 
            ng-show="frmColaboradores.funcao.$invalid && frmColaboradores.funcao.$touched">
            Função do colaborador é obrigatória </span>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Não sei mais o que de código devo colocar aqui, caso preciso de mais, só pedir...
Desde já, agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso por melhores praticas você tem que usar o ng-options no lugar do ng-repeat dentro de cada campo do select.
Para selecionar um campo quando voltar da base você tem que ter a mesma propriedade setada no ng-model 'colaborador.funcao_id'

Exemplo ng-init="colaborador.funcao_id = 1" ira filtrar o primeiro item

Espero ter ajudado

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


 <div  ng-app='myApp' >
        <div  ng-controller="funcoesController" class="form-group error">
            <label for="inputFuncao" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Função </label>

            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select name="funcao" ng-model="colaborador.funcao_id"  ng-required="true" 
                ng-options="f.id as f.descricao for f in tbfuncao">
                 <option value="">Selecione ... </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <span ng-init="colaborador.funcao_id = 1" class="help-inline" 
            ng-show="frmColaboradores.funcao.$invalid && frmColaboradores.funcao.$touched">
            Função do colaborador é obrigatória </span>
        </div>  
 </div>  

 <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('funcoesController', function($scope) {      

        $scope.tbfuncao = [
        { id:1, descricao: 'teste 1'},
        {id:2, descricao: 'teste 2'},
        {id:3, descricao: 'teste 3'},
        {id:4, descricao: 'teste 4'}
        ];  

    });
</script>

</body>
```